# SQLAlchemy OperationalError no such table - confusion with sqlite uri

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Help!
I'm really new to flask and I've been muddling along with all the tutorials I could find but I've run into a problem I can't figure out.

Here's my error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: User
[SQL: SELECT "User"."userId" AS "User_userId", "User".email AS "User_email", "User".password AS "User_password", "User".username AS "User_username", "User".lastlogin AS "User_lastlogin", "User".isauthenticated AS "User_isauthenticated" 
FROM "User" 
WHERE "User".email = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
[parameters: ('test@example.com', 1, 0)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

So I'm working on the signup form and I've solved all the other bugs. But here what I can make out from this error is that my database or table isn't being created.

Here's my code:

****init**.py:**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, session
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.utils import import_string
from complete.app import redirect_url

db = SQLAlchemy()
login_manager = LoginManager()

def create_app():
    """Create Flask application."""
    
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)

    @app.context_processor
    def inject_global_vars():
        return dict(appname="Ebay Listing Viewer")

    app.config.from_pyfile('configfile.py')    

    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():

        from .userauth.auth import auth_bp
        app.register_blueprint(auth_bp)

        db.create_all()

        from .models import User

        @login_manager.user_loader
        def load_user(user_id):
            return User.get(user)
        
        return app
```

**models.py:**

```
"""Data Models"""
from flask_login import UserMixin
from . import db


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'User'

    userid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(200))
    username = db.Column(db.String(1000))
    lastlogin = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    isauthenticated = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def get_id(self):
        return chr(self.userId)

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return self.isauthenticated

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User> {}'.format(self.username)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password = generate_password_hash(
            password,
            method='sha256'
        )
    
    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password, password)
```

**config.py:**

```
class Config(object):
    """Base config."""
    SECRET_KEY = environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    STATIC_FOLDER = 'static'
    TEMPLATES_FOLDER = 'templates'

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    FLASK_ENV = 'development'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = environ.get('DEV_DATABASE_URI')
```

**.env:**

```
#among other things...
DEV_DATABASE_URI=sqlite:///db.sqlite
```

There is a file called db.sqlite in my root folder (ie the same directory as init.py) but I'm not sure it's got anything in it. When I try to open it, it shows `The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding.` (I'm using VSCode).

I'm not quite sure how the database uri works - I've had a lot of looks around Google and everyone seems to think it's completely obvious. Is it the file path to my database file? Do I create the database file or is it automatically created?

I'm thinking the problem is likely to be that the database uri is wrong, but I dunno, I haven't got enough experience so maybe it's something completely different.

Thank you for taking the time to read and help!

Comment: Please share your models.py file. Are you creating a table User?

Comment: I've added the code. Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: Have your application display (or log) the value returned by `os.getcwd()`. That should be the folder where `sqlite:///db.sqlite` expects to find the "db.sqlite" file. It is where you expect?

Comment: I don't expect it to be anywhere because I'm very new to Flask, but it's in my root directory so I guess that's the right place...? But I thought it should be creating the db.sqlite file on it's own and it's not. I also tried creating it myself but getting the same error.